# Find <a> in specified <li> and append <span> to <a> jQuery

Tags: jquery, list, append

This is my setup:

```
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">MENU ENTRY</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">MENU ENTRY WITH SUBMENU</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">SUBMENU ENTRY</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SUBMENU ENTTY</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Now I tried to achieve the following with jQuery:

1. Check if "#nav li" has another "ul"
2. If so, find the "a"-Tag and append a "span"-Tag to it

Like this:

```
$("#nav li").has("ul").find("a").append('<span class="test">SOMETHING</span>');
```

Unfortunately the "span"-Tag is appended to all children "a"-Tags.

I tried to remove the class from the other "a"-Tags, but it does not work.

```
 $("#nav li ul li").find("a").remove(".test");
```

And here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LmDYg/6/

Help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I think we are all trying to guess which anchor tag you are actually trying to append to. please clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you

```
$('#nav li ul').prev('a').append('<span class="test">SOMETHING</span>');
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LmDYg/7/)**

Or you can use `children()` instead of `find()` to select only direct descendants of `<li>`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#nav li>ul').parent().children('a').append('<span class="test">SOMETHING</span>');
```

Comment: This causes the submenu entries to get the span. I want the specific li that has the ul to get the span.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are saying is that you only want to add it to the `a` which is a direct child of the `li`, in which case you would use `children` instead of `find`:

```
$("#nav li").has("ul").children("a").append('<span class="test">SOMETHING</span>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LmDYg/8/